# Google chart how to have two y axis

Tags: google-visualization

I want one chart showing temperature with one curve and humidity in percent with a second curve. 
I did it. 
However the curve of the temperature is small since max is around 22 while humidity Max is around 90.
Does Google chart support the possibility to have 2 scale with y axis? 
Thanks
Rod

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add a second y-axis.  You can do this by setting the `vAxes` option (which takes an object whose properties are objects with `vAxis` options), and use the `series` option to target each series to a specific axis.  Here's an example:

```
vAxes: {
    0: {
        // options for left y-axis
        title: 'Temperature'
    },
    1: {
        // options for right y-axis
        title: 'Humidity'
    }
},
series: {
    0: {
        // options for first data series (I'm assuming this is temperature)
        targetAxisIndex: 0 // target left axis
    },
    1: {
        // options for second data series (I'm assuming this is humidity)
        targetAxisIndex: 1 // target right axis
    }
}
```